# Pass timeout to socket.getaddrinfo

Tags: python, dns, timeout

Let's say I'm writing HTTP requests in Python and my DNS server goes down.

If I try:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://api.twilio.com', timeout=3)
```

and the DNS server is down, this can take upwards of 90 seconds, despite specifying a timeout value.

Furthermore the blocking call is `socket.getaddrinfo`, and it doesn't look like this takes a timeout parameter.

Is there a way to set a timeout on the DNS lookup?

Answer (score 8):

There is *no way* to pass a timeout to the getaddrinfo system call, because it does not accept a timeout argument. You can run the lookup in a thread, and then cancel it if it expires.

On Unix machines, you can modify `/etc/resolv.conf` to [set a timeout for addrinfo lookups](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolver.5.html).

Comment: `getaddrinfo` is not a system call, it's just a library function that's defined by POSIX and usually implemented by the C standard library (e.g. glibc).