# pycom urequests timeouts not working as expected

Tags: sockets, micropython

The standard Pycom urequests library (part of below) does not support user configurable timeouts.

```
def request(method, url, data=None, json=None, headers={}, stream=None):
    try:
        proto, dummy, host, path = url.split("/", 3)
    except ValueError:
        proto, dummy, host = url.split("/", 2)
        path = ""
    if proto == "http:":
        port = 80
    elif proto == "https:":
        import ussl
        port = 443
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported protocol: " + proto)

    if ":" in host:
        host, port = host.split(":", 1)
        port = int(port)

    ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port)
    ai = ai[0]
    s = usocket.socket(ai[0], ai[1], ai[2])

    try:
        s.connect(ai[-1])
```

If the server I'm trying to contact does not respond the code waits at

```
ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port)
```

for 30s before exiting with an OSError.

So I changed it using https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/pull/263/files as a guide

```
def request(method, url, data=None, json=None, headers={}, stream=None, timeout=5):
    try:
        proto, dummy, host, path = url.split("/", 3)
    except ValueError:
        proto, dummy, host = url.split("/", 2)
        path = ""
    if proto == "http:":
        port = 80
    elif proto == "https:":
        import ussl
        port = 443
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported protocol: " + proto)

    if ":" in host:
        host, port = host.split(":", 1)
        port = int(port)

    ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port)
    ai = ai[0]
    s = usocket.socket(ai[0], ai[1], ai[2])

    if timeout is not None:
        assert hasattr(usocket.socket, 'settimeout'), 'Socket does not support timeout'
        s.settimeout(timeout)

    try:
        s.connect(ai[-1])
```

It did me no good, the damn thing still waits for 30s if there is no server response. If anything I'm worse off because now it also waits for 5s after every server response before returning the data, whereas previously I'd get the data the instant the server responded.

I figure the 30s timeout must be accessible somewhere I just can't figure out where. I'm in a bit over my head here. Can anyone offer some suggestions?

Comment: Does [this method](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/usocket.html#usocket.socket.settimeout) not do what you want? The discussion also mentions using [`poll()`](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/uselect.html#uselect.poll) as a more portable alternative.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're not controlling the sockets the `urequests` library is.

Comment: Note that `getaddrinfo()` is a different beast and does not have a timeout parameter. I don't know if Micropython supports threads but if so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28120166/238704) answer may be relevant.

Comment: I tried to use poll() following the socket.settimeout(value) section of https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/usocket.html James but the program is waiting for a server address at ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port) and s is not declared till 2 lines later so I can't park the poll() stuff before the ai= line which is where I think it needs to be?